# Gstreamer , XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set error

Tags: python, linux, gstreamer

I was going through [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c) tutorial, when I encountered the following error.

OS description :
LINUX UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Input :
after compiling the tutorial successfully in the tutorial file using

```
gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

and executing the tutorial with

```
 ./basic-tutorial-1
```

as stated in the website I got this output.

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
shared memfd open() failed: Function not implemented
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
AL lib: (EE) ALCplaybackAlsa_open: Could not open playback device 'default': No such file or directory
```

I have read about `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` but I am not sure what file should I assign it to or if that is even the problem; [reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/872792/what-is-xdg-runtime-dir).

Comment: You want to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` or fix your application? I very much doubt that setting `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` would change anything... `if that is even the problem` Most probably it's not. I fear the problem is that it can't connect to any output - not to ALSA, not to Pulseaudio (`Cannot connect to server socket err`) seems like it, and not to Jack. Anyway, on ubuntu, you have systemd, try `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$USER` from https://serverfault.com/a/727994/499149 .

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I want to fix the application but I am not sure of the problem. Since u mentioned that the problem may be due to Cannot connect to server socket err, what is causing this error , maybe u can suggest a solution for that ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu Linux on window, will that be a problem ?

Comment: Problem solved by running it natively on linux, and to answer the question i post previous , yes it is a problem dont do that, go get a linux machine or VM or anything

Comment: `I am using ubuntu Linux on window, will that be a problem ?` Kind of, windows does not have linux [sound servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_server). I know nothing about windows - but you can install Jack or Pulseaudio on windows too. But gstreamer has most probably support for windows.